# 1 module.exports vs. module.exports for each function?

Tags: node.js

is there a different in efficiency between 1 module.export which contains many methods and module.export for each function in the module?

```
module.exports={
func1: function (req, res, next) {},
func2: function (req, res, next) {}
}
```

vs.

```
module.exports.func1 = function(){};
module.exports.funct2 = function(){};
```

I been told to investigate if there is a difference between the 2 options.
is one way better than the other?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the above two except that first one will export multiple functions whereas second one will exports one by one. both return the same object when you require in tis in another module. there is another way to exports module which is called single-value export, which is different than the one you have mentioned.

```
module.exports = function () { ··· };
```

Answer (score 0):

Practically, there's no difference. In CommonJS, `module.exports` is just another object. Both of these samples export the same functions as keys on that object.

The only real difference is that with the first example you reassign the `module.exports` object entirely whereas in the second example you're just assigning values to keys. This really wouldn't matter at all in any sane use-case.

In Node, the second example can be abbreviated to

```
exports.func1 = function() {};
exports.func2 = function() {};
```

The first form can be used to export a default value and some complimentary values, which is actually a fairly common pattern. Consider the following:

```
function express() {}
function Router() {}

module.exports = express
module.exports.Router = Router
```

This would allow you to import express via

```
var express = require('express')
var Router = express.Router
```

While slightly off-topic for this question, the ES6 analogs look like this:

```
export const func1 = function() {}
export const func2 = function() {}
```

or

```
export {
  func1,
  func2
}
```